# Spark: how to remove unnecessary characters in df column values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am having df like this,

```
+----+---+
| _c0|_c1|
+----+---+
|('a'| 2)|
|('b'| 4)|
|('c'| 6)|
+----+---+
```

I want like below how to do,

```
+----+---+
| _c0|_c1|
+----+---+
| a  | 2 |
| b  | 4 |
| c  | 6 |
+----+---+
```

If I try like this getting an error

```
df1.select(regexp_replace('_c0', "('", "c")).show()
```

> An error occurred while calling o789.showString. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 1 in stage 71.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   1.0 in stage 71.0 (TID 184, localhost, executor driver): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 2

Comment: `df.select(regexp_replace("value", "[()']", ""))`

Answer (score 2):

Like the other user has said it is necessary to escape special characters like brackets with a backslash. [Here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html) you can find a list of regex special characters. The following code uses two different approaches for your problem. With [regexp_extract](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract) we extract the single character between (' and ' in column _c0. With [regexp_replace](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace) we replace ) in the second column. You can of course use only the regexp_replace function with the regex "[()']" to achieve what you wanted. I just want to show you two different ways how you could tackle the problem.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
columns = ['_c0', '_c1']
vals = [("('a'", "2)"),("('b'", "4)"),("('c'", "6)")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
df = df.select(F.regexp_extract('_c0', "\('(\w)'", 1).alias('_c0')
             , F.regexp_replace("_c1", "\)", "").alias('_c1'))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+ 
|_c0|_c1| 
+---+---+ 
|  a|  2| 
|  b|  4| 
|  c|  6| 
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the brackets:

```
df1.select(regexp_replace('_c0', "\\('", "c")).show()
```

Comment: Thank you So much... But I am getting the ans like this,

a'
b'
c'

So how to clear this '